# connect from node.js to sql server with mssql fails

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to connect from node.js to SQL server database with mssql. I wrote the following code in my config.js:

```
const config = {
  "sqldb":{
    dialect: "mssql",
    server: "localhost\\MSSQLSERVER",
    user:"sa",
    password:"password",
    database:"mydb",
    port: 1433
  }
};
export default config;
```

and in my db.js I have:

```
import Sequelize from 'Sequelize';
import config from './config'
const sqldb = config.sqldb;

const Conn = new Sequelize(sqldb.database, sqldb.user, sqldb.password, {
  host:sqldb.server,
  dialect: sqldb.dialect,
});
export default Conn;
```

But I have the following error when I write queries:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Failed to connect to
>   localhost\MSSQLSERVER:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
>   localhost\MSSQLSERVER

I have enabled the TCP/IP for my SQL Server instance, and I have the SQL server browser running.

here you can see my SQL server services which are running:
[image]

Here you can see that the TCP port for Protocols for MSSQLSERVER is 1433.
[image]

the version of SQL Server is: Microsoft SQL Server 2016(SP1).

Comment: Is the MSSQLSERVER service listening on port 1433?

Comment: Yes I suppose, because the TCP port in Protocols for MSSQLSERVER is 1433, and TCP Dynamic Ports I set it to 0, which was null before. but in both case its not working. I updated the question

Comment: localhost\\MSSQLSERVER this is wrong

Comment: Have you tried using 127.0.0.1?

Comment: yes I tried with setting the server to 127.0.0.1 and still have this error: Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433

Comment: After I set the server name to 127.0.0.1 and the port to "the dynamic port" which was generated (1550) after I set the dynamic port to 0 and restart the server,  the problem was solved